# Calculate perspective transformation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, emgucv

[image]
How can I get the position of the "point" from walls perspective? I know the x,y,(z) coordinates from cameras perspective, and I know the edge points of the wall.
I want to calculate if the point stands in front of the wall, and on witch side of it (left, right).
My idea is to calculate a plane equation of the wall, and test if a perpendicular line from the point to the plane hits it in the boundaries of the wall.
Can I do this somehow without using the z coordinate (it is very inaccurate) and the angle between wall and camera is variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the xc,yc position of the center of the wall, you can transform the X,Y coordinates of the point in the new reference system.

First, translate the origin. If camera is in coordinates (0,0), the new coordinates of the poinx (X', Y', Z') in the 3D world will be

```
X' = X - xc
Y' = Y - yc
Z' = Z
```

(assuming from your image that the wall ortogonal to the XY plane)

Now you have to rotate around Z axis of an angle you know and obtain the final coordinates X'', Y'', Z'' with respect to the centre of the wall.

if the angle si aplha you derive the [rotational matrix around Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations)

```
     cos(alpha) -sin (alpha)    0
R = [sin(alpha) cos(alpha)      0]
         0           0          1
```

and obtain (matrix by vector moltiplication)

```
(X'', Y'', Z'') = R*(X',Y',Z')
```

you must obtain again that Z'' = Z

Now you can define the point are left or right to the middle of the wall checking if X'' > 0 or X'' < 0 (you can do also with Y'', it depends which value of alpha you have used)

---

If this answer assume something you do not already have (alpha, xc, yc, the 3D coordinates of the point) tell me and I will add a method or a strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If z coordinate is not important, you can forget it and use only x, y.

Instead of a plane, you fit a line to the wall's 2d points. Next, as you proposed, you calculate a line, that goes through the green point and is perpendicular to the wall's line and calculate the intersection point between the wall's line and the perpendicular line.

If the intersection point's x or y coordinate is inside the walls limits,

x_wall_min < x < x_wall_max or y_wall_min < y < y_wall_max,

than the point stands in front of the wall.

If the angle between the wall and the camera can vary, than you have to better define "left or right of the wall" as it might not be obvious for some angles.